# Electrostatic Plasma Confinement Fusor

Tags: nuclear-physics, plasma-physics, fusion

I wish to build a Fusor. Now, in order to build it, a high voltage is required generally achieved through Neon Sign Transformers. If I want to achieve voltages 25 kV or more, how am I supposed to do it? I could possibly use a voltage multiplier but I am not sure if it is a great idea. A voltage multiplier can not provide a very large current, so it may get discharged even before any fusion occurs. What are the other options that I have? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I could possibly use a voltage multiplier but I am not sure if it is a
> great idea.

Googling "how to make a fusor" turns up numerous step-by-step examples of working designs. Perhaps the best is [this one on Make](https://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/nuclear-fusor/).